# JAX-RS Resource Lifecycle Performance Impact

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

I know by default JAX-RS endpoints lifecycle is **once-per-request**, so that the request specific informations can be injected into the instance.

And we can also make an endpoints Singleton meaning **once-per-application**, in which the request specific informations cannot be injected into the instance rather it can be injected into the requested method.

**1.** So i would like to know **which approach is better** in terms of performance, either **once-per-request** or **once-per-application**.

**2.** I would also like to know the pros and cons of these approaches other the injecting request specific informations

**3.** Which approach you prefer to use in your API applications

Note: i have been using the once-per-request approach so far, but i always wonder is that is efficient, definitely its make coding easier and reusable.

Answer (score 9):

To start with your last question: I'm always using the default (per-request) and I seldom came to a point where I wanted to change this.

What might be a reason to prefer one over the other?

- If you want to serve some static content (maybe a welcome-document of your API) it makes sense to produce this content only once and hold it in a singleton resource class. But you can achieve the same by e.g. injecting an `@ApplicationScoped` CDI bean in a per-request scoped resource class.
- If you prefer injecting the `@xxxParam` values like `@QueryParam` as fields instead of method parameters you should use the per-request lifecycle. This is not supported for singletons. (This does not include injecting via `@Context`).

I made a little test to compare the performance of both. You can find the [sources](https://github.com/lefloh/jax-rs-performance) and the [results](https://github.com/lefloh/jax-rs-performance#results) on github. In short: I measured a difference from about 1.5 %. I don't think this should affect your application too much.
Comparing the [results of the JVisualVM monitoring](https://github.com/lefloh/jax-rs-performance/blob/master/results/visualvm) I would tend to say that the per-request test is using more memory but you should decide on your own if this really affects your application.

Comment: How does it scale with injections? Say we have several other request-scoped classes injected as dependencies of the resource vs having them as singletons. Would be nice to know how the results scale in such case.

Comment: Sorry, I did not test this. I don't think that this really affects the performance of your application.